# How to set min/max heap size for equinox osgi container

Tags: osgi, heap-memory, equinox

does anyone know how to set the max heap size when starting equinox?  I start the container from the command line as follows:

`java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.5.2.jar -console -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -XX:[MaxPermSize]=256M`

However, this has no effect on the max heap size and I end up with an OutOfMemoryException.  I am trying to deploy a war bundle using the catalina osgi bundle and spring-web-extender, so any tips on how to set java_opts for a tomcat osgi bundle would be appreciated also.

Thanks

Barry

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass the JVM heap args before calling the `-jar`

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.5.2.jar -console
```

[This useful link](http://blog.paulgu.com/2008/07/19/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap-size/) says

> Note that when you run java with -jar
>   option, anything after -jar jar-file
>   will be treated as application
>   arguments. So you should always put
>   JVM options before -jar.